# How to test 10 threads with JMeter?

Tags: configuration, jmeter

1. Reach 10 threads
   a. The 10 threads should be created in a 1-minute period (i.e. - after 60 seconds, thread number 10 will kick in)
2. Each thread should
   a. Execute an HTTP request to http://blazedemo.com
   i. Verify that the word ‘welcome’ is in the body of the response
   b. Then, wait for 10 secs
   c. Execute an HTTP request to http://blazedemo.com/register
   i. Wait 5 seconds before the request is executed.
   d. Extract the XSRF token from the response header.
   e. Use Beanshell script to log the extracted token to the Jmeter log.

Comment: Please format Your question

Comment: Please share what you have done so far. It is not possible to guide you here from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration to implement 10 users ramping up for 1 minute would be the following:

   [image]
2. [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for http://blazedemo.com/ would be:

   [image]
3. To check `Welcome` text presence use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

   [image]
4. To wait for 10 seconds use [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

   [image]
5. To open http://blazedemo.com/register add another HTTP Request sampler:

   [image]
6. To wait for 5 seconds before request use [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer)

   [image]
7. To extract XSRF Token use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

   [image]
8. I don't know who told you to use Beanshell, you need to make this person aware that since [JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as [Groovy has much better performance and more features comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/). In order to print the tokens for each user add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of 2nd HTTP Request sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   log.info("Token for user: " + ctx.getThreadNum() + " is: " + vars.get("token"));
   ```

   [image]

More information:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#building)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

Comment: Dmitri - this question needs to be closed, not answered. It is so unclear (and lacking effort) that it should be closed and deleted in its current state. I wonder if it is a homework on an academic course.